# Trouble binding list of objects to Datagrid .Net WebForms

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I'm using C# and WebForms and running into an issue. I have a class like this:

```
 public class Foo
 {
      public int _touchID;
      public string _touchName;
  }
```

Then I have a Dao object that returns a `List`of `Foo` and I want to bind that list to a `DataGrid`.

```
public List<Foo> getFooList()
    { //get my list and whatnot}
```

I bind it to my `asp:DataGrid` like this:

```
TouchGrid.DataSource = dao.getFooList();
TouchGrid.DataBind();
```

The aspx page is like this:

```
 <asp:DataGrid ID="TouchGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="ID" DataField="_touchID"></asp:BoundColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Touch">
            <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="touchName" text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "_touchname") %>' runat="server"/>
                  <%--<div class="touchDescriptionHidden"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "_description")%></div>--%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

When I run the code, I get a runtime exception because

> A field or property with the name '_touchID' was not found on the
>   selected data source.

I've tried using `DataItem._touchID` but I got the same error using that. I also tried to autogenerate the columns to see if I could get some hint as to why this is failing but I get a message saying

> Unable to autogenerate columns for selected datasource

I know I'm missing something but I'm not sure exactly what. If I debug on the `DataBind` line and look at the `DataSource`, I can see my objects just fine:

> TouchGrid.DataSource
>
> ```
>  [0] - _touchID=1 | _name="stuff"  
>  [1] - _touchID=2 | _name="otherStuff"
> ```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d76z3ck.aspx) mechanism does not work with class fields, but with class properties.

So you need to convert the fields to properties (also this a requested OOP principle).

```
public class Foo
 {
      public int _touchID;
      public string _touchName;
  }

becomes

public class Foo
 {
      public int TouchID {get; set;}
      public string TouchName {get; set;}
  }
```

Comment: nice. I happened to overlook that. Thanks. I'll accept when I can.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Foo
{
  public int TouchID {get; set;}
  public string TouchName {get; set;}
}
```

Also change data binding as follows

```
<asp:Label ID="touchName" 
text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.TouchName") %>' runat="server"/>
```

Should work..